# Dispatch one event on updating multiple data or dispatch an event for every single field

Tags: event-sourcing

at the moment, I am learning Event Sourcing. I used CRUD for a long time now and I guess I'm still kinda stuck in the CRUD-way.

Well, now to my question:

I event-sourced a part of my application, where I create something called a `Job`. A `Job` can have:

- `title`
- `description`
- `created_at`

So creating this `Job` is easy - but what do I do when it comes to updating?

Is it an anti pattern to dispatch an event like `JobUpdated`, which contains changes to the `title` and possibly the `description`? Or should I dispatch multiple events like:

- `JobTitleChanged`
- `JobDescriptionChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, where `Updated` events seem to be the best you can do, a lot will come down to whether it's more common for one of title or description to be edited or for them to be edited together.  If the former, specific field updates (e.g. `JobTitleUpdated`) are better, as they at least allow for consumers which don't care about the title field to easily ignore those events, but if a particular transaction issues both `JobTitleUpdated` and a `JobDescriptionUpdated` events, the context that those events were in the same transaction is difficult to reliably reconstruct from the separate events.

In general, `Updated` events aren't particularly rich: they capture what changed, but lose other context (most often the why).  In a hotel, for instance, you could have a `RoomStatusUpdated` event (e.g. `RoomStatusUpdated(VacantDirty)`), but there are a lot of different reasons for that, so it might be better to have `GuestCheckedIn`, `GuestCheckedOut`, `RoomCleaned`, `RoomOutOfOrder` etc. events.